# Что делать с большими и сложными шаблонами в Twig

Tags: php, symfony2, twig, шаблонизаторы

В интернет магазине есть история заказов Пользователя, и есть два вида Пользователей: Юрики и Физики. И фишка в том, что для Юриков в истории заказов показывается больше информации, неженли для Физиков. И из-за этого в шаблоне, который отображает историю заказов появляются всякие if'ы, типа

```
{% if user.isB2b() %}
    <div>bla-bla-bla</div>
{% endif %}
```

Так ещё и помимо этого увеличивается наш Controller, который должен получать доп. данные от сервисов для Юриков.

Есть ли какая-нибудь возможность сделать это более красиво, прозрачно? Может быть есть какие-нибудь техники? А то у меня даже идей нет...

Comment: Разные шаблоны для юридических и физических лиц?

Comment: @Visman ну так можно сделать, но тогда будет копипаст, что еще хуже

Comment: Я сначала, было, подумал, что речь о физиках и юристах )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынести отличающуюся информацию в отдельный блок. Может быть несколько блоков, но в одном файле. Благо, наследование twig позволяет проворачивать любые изощрения. Копипаста будет ноль. Выглядеть будет элегантно ;) - `if` будет всего один.

Comment: Да, но учитывая то, что этими if'ами шаблон пронизан полностью мы очень усложним жизнь верстальщикам да и себе... Мы конечно же думали про блоки

Comment: Я вижу всего 2 варианта: 1. Вынести в отдельный файл блоками. 2. Сделать отдельный вид для каждого типа пользователя. Выбирайте, что вам больше подходит.